# Why aren't WorkDayBeg and WorkDayEnd working in Date::Manip?

Tags: perl, date

I have this at the top of my personal configuration file (as well as holidays, which are being respected, so I know the file is being read...):

```
WorkDayBeg = 08:00
WorkDayEnd = 17:00
```

... and yet when I do a delta on 08:00 to 17:00 in business mode, it says 8 hours instead of 9.  It is defaulting to a work day of 09:00 to 17:00.

Any idea why?

Comment: Post the code that is giving you the error.

Comment: Maybe it's giving you an hour off for lunch? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not observe that behavior:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Date::Manip;

Date_Init('WorkDayBeg = 08:00', 'WorkDayEnd = 17:00');

print 'Not in business mode: ',
    DateCalc(ParseDate('8:00'), ParseDate('17:00')), "\n",
    'In business mode: ',
    DateCalc(ParseDate('8:00'), ParseDate('17:00'), undef, 2), "\n";
```

```
C:\Temp> bun
Not in business mode: +0:0:0:0:9:0:0
In business mode: +0:0:0:1:0:0:0
```

As expected, the difference is nine hours if not in business mode and a working day if in business mode.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I don't even want to admit what had me confused, but let's suffice it to say that my ensuing code converting the business days/hours into pure hours was where the problem lay.  Thank you for the head check.